# Unit test IOException for InputStream

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Is there a way to unit test the following code without using **PowerMock**? We have sonar unit test code coverage and it does not recognise code tested via PowerMockRunner. So I was looking for a way to simulate **IOException** or use Mockito somehow to test this code so that it throws exception.

```
public void readFile(byte[] bytes) {    
    try (final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
       .....
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SystemException("Error reading file");
    }
}



@Test(expected = SystemException.class)
public void testException {
}
```

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Which code coverage tool are you using?  I have been successful in getting SonarQube unit test coverage in code tested with PowerMock using both Cobertura and JaCoCo.

Comment: There is no way to mock that without PowerMockito, and no input will ever cause that exception with a `ByteArrayInputStream`. I think your best option is to go with @tddmonkey's answer. It doesn't answer your original question, but I think it solves your actual problem.

EDIT: Take a look at @superfav's answer for a general example of moving calls to methods in order to utilize Mockito.

Comment: @ToddDunlap I am using SonarQube Version 5.2 and it completely ignores unit test coverage for tests marked with  @Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Comment: But what is generating the unit test coverage data?  Are you sure that it is SonarQube actually generating the data and not just displaying it?  In my experience, SonarQube reads in coverage data produced by some other tool.  With Cobertura, you don't have to do anything special to get it to work with PowerMock.  With JaCoCo, there are options, but I typically add a coverage profile to my Maven build that configures JaCoCo in a way that is compatible with PowerMock, so that the coverage data covers PowerMock code and I see it all in SonarQube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ByteArrayInputStream` will never throw an Exception so subsequently your `try` / `catch` is pointless.  Just create the `ByteArrayInputStream` and use it directly and dump the exception handling.  If you check the method signatures of `ByteArrayInputStream` you'll notice that the exceptions are removed so you don't have to worry about it.

Update:

You can safely interact with the `ByteArrayInputStream` like this:

```
public void readFile(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ....
    // no need to close the inputStream as it's a NO-OP
}
```

Comment: The `ByteArrayInputStream` might throw an `IOException` when it is auto closed. Eclipse says `Unhandled exception type IOException thrown by automatic close() invocation on inputStream`.

Comment: No it won't - the `close` method is a noop.  There's no reason to actually close a `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: Quoting the Javadoc - `Closing a ByteArrayInputStream has no effect.`

Comment: You are correct but you still have to handle the exception.

Comment: You don't! The OP is *explicitly* using it as a `ByteArrayInputStream` not a generic `InputStream` so there is no need to do any exception handling at all.  It can all be removed from the code

Comment: If he changes his declaration, then sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)` by a method that creates and returns an `InputStream` from a byte array. If you create an interface for that, lets say

```
interface InputStreamFactory {
  InputStream from(byte[] bytes);
}
```

Then you can have an implementation that returns a `ByteArrayInputStream` for production code and one that returns an object that throws `IOException` for the test. And maybe someday a `BufferedInputStream` one, and so on.

```
private final InputStreamFactory factory;

[...]

public void readFile(byte[] bytes) {    
    try (final InputStream inputStream = factory.from(bytes)) {
    ...
```

Comment: This answers the OP's original question, but it's usually overkill to do something like this in my experience.